# Is having a Persistent Login Cookie ("Remember me") that never expires a good idea?

Tags: cookies, authentication, remember-me

In the most recommended solution for Persistent Login Cookies, a user's "Remember me" `Cookie` is always renewed with a **new token** when they login with their Persistent Login Cookie.  Let's say you set an `expiry date` of `30 days` for the `Cookie`, this means that as long as they access the site once a month, they will never, **ever** have to enter their password again since the renewed Cookie will keep pushing the expiry date 30 days into the future.

**Is this a good idea?**

If not, and we wanted to force them to login at least once a month, then how would we know when their *first* Persistent Login Cookie was issued considering we can't retrieve the `expiry date` of a `Cookie`?

Would we have to store the timestamp of the first `Cookie` in the Cookies themselves and keep track of it that way and then have the site delete the cookie when the original timestamp has expired?

Or am I **overthinking** all of this and there is no problem with a user that never has to login again (unless, of course, they are accessing a critical section of the site, such as their Account or Payment page)?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be a good idea?

Comment: @woz: I'm not sure, that's why I'm asking. The only Cons I can think of are if the user does not use their password often, they might forget it and might not even remember the email they signed up with so they won't be able to retrieve it, and the other is maybe someone sells their PC/cellphone without clearing all their data, and then someone can continuously access their account (except the more sensitive parts) forever. Yup, I know it's a stretch, but I'm just thinking out loud here and I want to make sure it's OK for a Cookie never to expire on a regular-type site before I implement it.

Comment: The same problems occur with any mobile apps that save your password an re-authenticate for you when you open them, e.g. Facebook, Mint.com, etc., so I don't think it would be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the nature of the information which is being accessed on the site, for stackoverflow it's ok for more sensitive information like access to a bank web site, never.

Comment: So for an SO type site, it's OK to have a Persistent Login Cookie that never expires?

Comment: since the cookie is per user, unless multiple people are using the same account (which is a bad practice in any case why not?)